# PHP - count frequency of array values

Tags: php, arrays, count, frequency

Is there a way in php to count how often a value exists in a large array?

So if I have an array like this:

```
$array = "1,2,3,4,joe,1,2,3,joe,joe,4,5,1,6,7,8,9,joe";
```

is there a way to output a new array that tells me (and sorts) which is used most and how many for each?

```
$result = array(
    [joe] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] =>2
    etc...
    )
```

I've seen the php array_count_values, but can this be sorted by most -> least? or is there an easier way?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: step 1, make it an array using the explode-function in PHP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sort them after counting them with [`arsort()`](http://php.net/arsort)

```
$result = array_count_values(explode(',', $array));
arsort($result);

Array
(
    [joe] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [9] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 1
)
```

Comment: and to make it sort in descending order, use the rsort function instead of ordinary sort.

Comment: or ksort to organize by key in ascending order